# Bootstrap angular two column desktop view to (click to open) list-detail two page view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have this angular application with bootstrap 4 beta. In my app component template, I am using two column layout. First column has servers and second column has server details.

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h1>Servers</h1>
            <ul>
              <app-server-list></app-server-list>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 d-block d-sm-none">
            <h1>server details</h1>
            <app-server-detail></app-server-detail>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

This works fine on desktop. When the user clicks on server, server details are shown on second column.
On mobile view, I want to hide the server list column and show server details column when the user clicks on a server from the list. I can show/hide columns using bootstrap classes. But how to do that with angular.

Because the server list is rendered with app-server-list component, when the click event happens on one of the server from server list, how to update classes for the first column in app-component which is in the different component.

Similarly, when the user clicks the close button server detail component, how to add the classes back to two columns for hiding/showing them.

One idea I have is to create a service component and use a rx/js subject in that. the app component which has the bootstrap column html template can listen to this subject and update class assignment.

Is this the best way to make this happen? Are there any other options which I can use that I am not able to think of. I am relatively new to angular so I am little bit clue less.
Please help.

Comment: Provide a pen or fiddle, show us your code, some minimal example what you are trying to do and someone may be able to help. You are talking about some buttons open/close, there are no buttons in your entire code, there is some component/directive and we have no clue what's happening there.

Comment: ok, I will create a sample project and provide the code by tomorrow.